# Generate regular expression from diff

Tags: regex, string, diff

I am looking for a way to generate regex from based on the differences between 2 input strings. The regex can then be used to match the 3rd string that is also similar to the 2 input strings.

For example, given 3 strings: f1, f2, and f3

f1:

```
111xxx222
```

f2:

```
111yyy222
```

f3:

```
111zzz222
```

I am wondering if there is a generic way to generate the following regex from f1 and f2 that can be used to extract "zzz" in f3:

```
111(.*)222
```

Comment: Let's see if I understand this. You want to keep the "static" part of the string, something that is equal in the previous strings, use that to locate what is different via a regex?

Comment: yes, that is correct. I would like to generate a pattern from the 2 input strings and use it to extract (or locate) the differences in the 3rd string

Comment: 111(.*)222 should probably be 111(.*?)222. It would help if you could provide some examples that are a bit more real than those and explain what is the context of your request. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

[Now you have two problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247).

You need to think hard about what the set of possible strings are, and what is the "right" regular expression for each input pair.  I know it seems obvious to you right now but convincing your algorithm to do what you expect may be harder than you think.  A little TDD is always a good idea: try to think of some pathological cases.

In your example, why shouldn't it generate something like one of these, instead of your suggestion (see @M42's answer for the first one)?:

```
111(...)222
111(...*)222
111(...+)222
111(..*)222
111(...?)222
(.*)111(.*)222(.*)
etc.
```

What would you like to happen if the third string is one of these?  *Or the second?*

```
1111zzz222
111zzz2222
0111zzz222
111zzz2223
111zzzz222
111zz222
11zzz222
111zzz22
111zzz
zzz222
111xyz222
1z1z1z222
111222
1111222
1112222
etc.
```

If (as I suspect) you already know that some of these cases are going to be impossible, then you already know more about the possible structure of the strings than you are letting on.  And if that's the case, you should probably just parse the strings and have done.

If you really really really want to try this anyway then the first thing you need to figure out is whether you want to match "[longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)" or some variation of "[longest common substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)".

If you really *are* running this against arbitrary strings, then once you think you have a good algorithm, make sure to test it against a *lot* of sample data (which should be pretty easy to generate ...)

Comment: please give the "two problems" quote a rest.  It doesn't help the beginners, and the rest of us have heard it before: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_qdr=all&q="now+(they+OR+you)+have+two+problems"+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: @Alan: any criticism of the rest of my answer?  Do you think the OP is 100% on the right track with this "generate-me-a-regex" approach?  I've only used the quote in one place that I can recall (namely: on this page), and since I think it is utterly and precisely to the point in this particular case, I'll wait to give it a rest until I feel like I've been overusing it.  Until then, here's a link to a page that describes my own thoughs on regular expressions very well: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Comment: I didn't mean *you* had overused it, just that it's been done to death already.  Starting an answer with a worn-out zinger tends to make the author sound ignorant and prejudiced, which is unfortunate in this case, since this is actually a good answer.

Comment: @Alan - good point.  I'm going to leave it, since I really think it is appropriate in this case.  Attention @Derek the asker: regular expressions are **awesome**, but they aren't always the best choice, is all I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the 2 strings are equal length, with Perl you can do:

```
my @x = split//,'111xxx222';
my @y = split//,'111yyy222';
my $r;
for my $i(0..$#x) {
    $r .= $x[$i] eq $y[$i] ? $x[$i] : '.';
}
$r =~ s/(\.+)/($1)/g;
print $r
```

output:

```
111(...)222
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a much nicer way to do this but, in Python:

```
import re

f1 = "111xxx222"
f2 = "111yyy222"
f3 = "111zzz222"

pre = []
post = []
found_diff = 0

for i in range(len(f1)):
    if f1[i] == f2[i]:
        if found_diff == 0:
            pre.append(f1[i])
        else:
            post.append(f1[i])
    else:
        found_diff = 1

regex = "".join(pre) + "(.*)" + "".join(post)

re.compile(regex)
print re.match(regex, f3).group(1)
```

prints zzz.

NB this won't work if the first two strings are not the same length.

Answer (score 0):

The Python std lib includes a diff module, difflib.  Here is a stab at your problem:

```
>>> import difflib
>>> f1 = "111xxx222"
>>> f2 = "111yyy222"
>>> sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=f1, b=f2)
>>> diff_re = ''
>>> for a,b,n in sm.get_matching_blocks():
...   if not n: continue
...   if diff_re: diff_re += "(.*)"
...   diff_re += f1[a:a+n]
...
>>> print diff_re
'111(.*)222'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a really interesting problem, particularly if it's generalised to something like "given N strings, find the simplest, most restrictive regex R that matches them". In the test data given, that would probably yield unhelpful answers like "111(xxx|yyy)222", so the question might need to be fine-tuned.

This does sound like the kind of pure compsci question that ought to have had a paper written about it...